# Is Interface remain fully abstract after adding default method in java 1.8?

Tags: java, methods, interface, java-8

Is Interface remain  fully abstract after adding default method in java 1.8?

I am sorry if I was not able to state the question clearly.

Comment: Yes, it'll remain abstract and you'll have to provide implementation class for it.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "fully" abstract?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even if you have only one default method in your interface, it will be abstract. You will have to provide implementing class to instantiate an object. Note that `default` methods added in Java 8 has special purpose. From [Java doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/defaultmethods.html):

> Default methods enable you to add new functionality to the interfaces
>   of your libraries and ensure binary compatibility with code written
>   for older versions of those interfaces.

So you should use `default` methods judiciously.

Comment: Why do you conclude that "*you should use `default` methods judiciously*"? I don't necessarily disagree, but I don't see how your assertion follows from the quote.

Comment: Think about a scenario where a class implements 2 interfaces and both interfaces have a default method with the same signature, you would get compile time error.

Comment: Sure, but is that a problem? How could you hope to implement two different interfaces that specify different behavior for the same method anyways? I don't see why one should be judicious in their use of `default` methods simply because there's a slight risk that implementors might do something irrational.

Comment: Yes, that is the problem. Suppose client code is implementing interfaces from 2 libraries and developers of these 2 libraries decide to provide default method implementation with the same signature, resulting in broken code at client's end.

Comment: Sure, that is a *theoretical* danger. In practice this doesn't really make sense; why would you implement two different interfaces that do different things with the same method? Again though, I'm not objecting to suggesting interface designers being careful. I'm asking *where in your answer* you raise these issues.

Comment: I see your point, I should have explained it in my answer. But now it's in comments so users can see what I meant :)

Answer (score 5):

[JLS8 §9.1.1.1. (Abstract Interfaces)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.1.1.1) clearly states (emphasis mine):

> **Every interface is implicitly abstract.** This modifier is obsolete and should not be used in new programs.

Besides that, the term "fully abstract" does not make sense to me. What should it mean? What would "partially abstract" mean? There is no concept like that.

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion, Yes. In fact Default methods in interfaces has bridge down the differences between interfaces and abstract classes. Default methods will help in implementing the interface without breaking the existing code.

**Important points about java interface default methods:**

> 1. Java 8 interface default methods will help us in avoiding utility classes, such as all the Collections class method can be provided in
>      the interfaces itself.
> 2. Java interface default methods will help us in removing base implementation classes, we can provide default implementation and the
>      implementation classes can chose which one to override.
> 3. One of the major reason for introducing default methods in interfaces is to enhance the Collections API in Java 8 to support
>      lambda expressions. If any class in the hierarchy has a method with
>      same signature, then default methods become irrelevant.
> 4. A default method cannot override a method from java.lang.Object. The reasoning is very simple, it’s because Object is the base class
>      for all the java classes. So even if we have Object class methods
>      defined as default methods in interfaces, it will be useless because
>      Object class method will always be used. That’s why to avoid
>      confusion, we can’t have default methods that are overriding Object
>      class methods.
> 5. Java interface default methods are also referred to as Defender Methods or Virtual extension methods.

Source: [Java 8 Interface Changes – static method, default method](http://www.journaldev.com/2752/java-8-interface-changes-static-method-default-method)

**Example:**

Before Java 8 my interface was more like below where we could not add methods with implementations:

```
public interface OldInterface {
    public void existingMethod();
}
```

After Java 8 we can add default methods, so new interface will be like:

```
public interface OldInterface {
    public void existingMethod();

    default public void newDefaultMethod() {
        System.out.println("Default Interface method added in Java 8");
    }
}
```

Following class will work fine:

```
public class OldInterfaceImpl implements OldInterface {
    public void existingMethod() {
     // existing implementation is here…
    }
}
```

we can create an instance of OldInterfaceImpl:

```
OldInterfaceImpl obj = new OldInterfaceImpl ();
// print “New default method add in interface”
obj.newDefaultMethod();
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you're asking if there's is something "concrete" or "non-abstract" about an interface with default methods. The answer is no. Classes have state stored in instance fields, and are concretely associated with a particular instance of a class. Interfaces have no state (i.e. they cannot define fields), and therefore are "fully abstract" to use your term.

Java 8 adds default methods, so now you can specify the default behavior of a method, but *only in terms of other methods in the interface*, not in terms of any state in the object (since there is no such object at the time the method is being defined). Conceptually a default method simply lets implementations avoid boilerplate code when a method can be defined entirely in terms of other methods in the interface. For example `Collection.addAll()` can be defined in terms of `Collection.add()` called in a loop. Doing so doesn't affect the state of any classes that implement the interface - they still have complete control over the class by defining all the non-default methods.

Contrast this with an abstract class, which *can* have instance fields, and therefore has some concrete state associated with each instance that sub-classes cannot prevent.